# Kohana ORM - mysql conditional inside order_by() method

Tags: orm, sql-order-by, kohana

Today I have an specific "issue" to solve with Kohana (3.3) orm order_by method.
I need rewrite the order_by() method to accept anything like that:

```
->order_by("IF(ISNULL(foo) OR foo = '', 1, 0), foo", "ASC")
```

(This conditional put all null values in the end of query result).
But, the orm escape the query with " **`** " then it not work.

```
ORDER BY `IF(ISNULL(foo) OR foo = "", 1, 0), foo` ASC
```

I can mount this query using DB::query(), but I need use that conditional in all order_by query on my system.

Comment: [Solved] ->order_by(DB::expr("IF(ISNULL(foo) OR foo = '', 1, 0), foo"), "ASC")

Answer (score 2):

Try DB::expr(), its work

```
->order_by(DB::expr("IF(ISNULL(foo) OR foo = '', 1, 0), foo"), "ASC")
```